# how to display data in bulleted list in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I am new to asp.net and I want to display data in `Bulleted list`.I am fetching items using following `Foreach` loop and want to display in a `Bulleted list` in asp.net.

**Result.aspx.cs**

```
foreach (XmlElement statement1 in node2statements.ChildNodes)
{
var st = statement1.InnerText.ToString();                      
}
```

**Result.aspx**

```
<ul id="section1">
<li>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a small example to demonstrate how to bind data from an xml file to a bulletedList. I used a [XmlDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource(v=vs.110).aspx) object. First I used an xml file

**products.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<list>
  <product id="123">
    <name>product a</name>
    <price>123.45</price>
  </product>
  <product id="123">
    <name>product b</name>
    <price>123.45</price>
  </product>
</list>
```

and I created **a transform file** - as only attributes will be accesible in controls. Credit goes to [**Darin Dimitrov**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) for pointing out that

> ... a bug in XmlDataSource that prevents you to bind to values of xml
>   nodes. It works with attributes only

**transform.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="list">
    <list>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="product"/>
    </list>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="product">
    <product>
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="price">
        <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </product>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then I did two examples - first one demonstrates **how to use it within the page**.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h3>Bulleted List with XML binding</h3>
        <asp:BulletedList ID="blPageOnly" runat="server" DataValueField="id" DataTextField="name" DataSourceID="xmlSource"></asp:BulletedList>
        <asp:XmlDataSource ID="xmlSource" runat="server" DataFile="~/app_data/products.xml" TransformFile="~/app_data/transform.xsl" XPath="list/product"></asp:XmlDataSource>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Bulleted List with XML binding - code behind</h3>
        <asp:BulletedList ID="blCodeBehind" runat="server"></asp:BulletedList>
    </div>
</form>
```

Second one shows how to **bind xml file from code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        XmlDataSource xmlSource = new XmlDataSource()
        {
            DataFile = "~/app_data/products.xml",
            XPath="list/product",
            TransformFile = "~/app_data/transform.xsl"
        };

        blCodeBehind.DataSource = xmlSource;
        blCodeBehind.DataTextField = "name";
        blCodeBehind.DataValueField = "id";

        blCodeBehind.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Will result in

[image: BulletedList databinding with XmlDataSource]

I hope you can adapt my code to help you out!

Answer (score 0):

Make use of asp:Repeater and bind it with your Child Nodes

Inside the item template of repeater you can define UL and LI and assign them to statement1

Comment: sorry to ask stupid question but can you please tell me how can a bind repeater with Childnodes?

Comment: You should try to google it around. I've suggested you a way which will definitely work for the kind of format you need.